# aspnetboiletplate - send email with attachments

Tags: email, aspnetboilerplate

I have an aspnetboilerplate template, .netcore & angular (free version). I am trying to find a way to attach a word document to an email using the IEmailSender but cant find the proper way of doing so. Have already checked the [Email Sending](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Email-Sending?searchKey=email) but there is no hint for attaching file to an email. 
Does anyone have a sample code that could possibly share with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code snippet to send an email with attachment:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage
            {
                Subject = "Subject",
                Body = "Message",
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                To = { "toaddress@gmail.com"},
                From = new MailAddress("fromaddress@gmail.com")
            };

            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(_env.WebRootPath + "\\pp.jpg"));
            _emailSender.SendAsync(mail);
```

Comment: If someone's here and was wondering why this works here's the interface of the EmailSender in Abp

`public interface IEmailSender
{
Task QueueAsync( string to , string subject , string body , bool isBodyHtml = true );

Task SendAsync( string to , string subject , string body , bool isBodyHtml = true );

Task SendAsync( string from , string to , string subject , string body , bool isBodyHtml = true );

Task SendAsync( MailMessage mail , bool normalize = true );
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly construct a MailMessage and pass it to `IEmailSender.SendAsync(mailMessage)`.

See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/94ebd48fd959cd460d97b809317a959e45c94067/src/Abp/Net/Mail/EmailSenderBase.cs#L66

If you are using MailKit, the underlying implementation will convert the Mail message object into MimeMessage and send it via Mailkit

See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/94ebd48fd959cd460d97b809317a959e45c94067/src/Abp.MailKit/MailKitEmailSender.cs#L42-L50

**MimeMessage** implementation
https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/bcc7030b61c0c83a10eab7e7a5d689efd923038d/MimeKit/MimeMessage.cs#L3494